# Stack Exchange blocks web.archive.org from archiving questions in Wayback Machine

Tags: bug, rate-limiting, archive

I recently tried to find out why Google doesn't index a question I asked on *[Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/tour)* (in beta). For fun, I tried archiving it on web.archive.org, but to my surprise SE blocked the request with `Reason: Request rate`. Is that on purpose?

Is there a reason why questions shouldn't be archived? The content is Creative Commons licensed. If there's something interesting for historians in 50 years, why not?

Here's a screenshot of what I get here https://web.archive.org/web/20211019044811/http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

[image]

@Glorfindel had the great idea of comparing what's in the archive between different sites. It turns out that *[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)* never had a single 4xx problem (yellow), whereas *Bioinformatics* almost always does:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try waiting and trying again? If that didn't work, did you try contacting team@stackexchange.com as the message suggests?

Comment: Your IP address is in that picture, are you okay with that?

Comment: It's interesting to compare the overviews for several sites: `https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/` `https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://apple.stackexchange.com/` `https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/` `https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://chess.stackexchange.com/` Bioinformatics has a lot of 'not founds' this year ...

Comment: @bobble it's likely to be the IP address of one of the Wayback Machine servers.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I have waited, and I have emailed, but I still thought why not ask the question because this is very different from a general block for an end user. In this case it's the archiver that's blocked, not me. That's why I asked here, it's a specifically interesting case of blocking.

Comment: The rate limiter applies to the entire network of SE sites, in aggregate. Once someone makes too many requests on one or more SE sites put together, access to *all* sites is restricted.

Comment: @bobble It's the IP of the web archive server, not mine. But thanks for asking!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320850/323179

Answer (score 8):

One of the ways that Stack Exchange defends itself from Denial of Service and spam attacks is by limiting the number of requests from a single source. This is usually only temporary as the message says.

Anyone anywhere on the internet can press that button and one of the Wayback servers will try to contact Stack Exchange's servers to crawl that page. The Stack Exchange defences probably don't treat Wayback server specially so they see it as making an unusual number of requests and block it.

All we can advise you to do on Meta is follow the instructions and contact team@stackexchange.com to see whether they will adjust the rate limiter for this case.

Comment: I have already written an email. The pattern of bioinformatics vs apple is quite interesting though, isn't it? Bioinformatics is almost always blocked, Apple never.

Comment: The only other thing you need is patience then. Normal response time is 6-8 somethings. What you're seeing is likely Wayback's autocrawling rather than the manual crawl you kicked off, it's quite possible they work differently.

Comment: Have you seen this image? The crawl almost always goes 4xx: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4nr8.png The discrepancy to Apple is huge. Am I missing something?

Comment: Strange thing is (and take it with a pinch of salt - since I don't work here) - I'm half certain they all get served by the same servers.